# openLDAP won't start after including second schema

Tags: openldap

I have a Mac I have installed openLDAP on (using Macports).  I have gotten the system up and am able to create objects.  The only schema I have configured in the slapd.conf is core.schema.

I am looking to add nis.schema, but when i try this the `slapd -d3` command won't work for me.  Specifically, it says:

```
5b994529 @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.28 (Oct 14 2016 16:25:43) $
    root@osx234.apple.com:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/OpenLDAP/OpenLDAP-523.30.2~39/TempContent/Objects/servers/slapd
5b994529 daemon: SLAP_SOCK_INIT: dtblsize=256
5b994529 daemon_init: listen on ldap:///
5b994529 daemon_init: 1 listeners to open...
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap:///)
5b994529 daemon: listener initialized ldap:///
5b994529 daemon_init: 2 listeners opened
5b994529 daemon_init: [0]DNSServiceRegister
ldap_create
5b994529 slapd init: initiated server.
5b994529 int pws_auxprop_init(const sasl_utils_t *, int, int *, sasl_auxprop_plug_t **, const char *): entered5b994529 slap_sasl_init: initialized!
5b994529 bdb_back_initialize: initialize BDB backend
5b994529 bdb_back_initialize: Berkeley DB 4.7.25: (May 15, 2008)
5b994529 hdb_back_initialize: initialize HDB backend
5b994529 hdb_back_initialize: Berkeley DB 4.7.25: (May 15, 2008)
5b994529 ==> OD Locales overlay initialize called 
5b994529 ==> translucent_initialize
5b994529 slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
5b994529 slapd stopped.
5b994529 connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
tlsst_destroy()
```

I'm unable to locate any logs for this to narrow down the cause.  How can I import this schema and still have slapd run successfully?

### Edit

I have run slapd -d-1 for additional logging.  I can provide the full log if needed, but I am seeing the following as the likely culprit:

```
5b9a54a1 /opt/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema: line 203 (objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.6 NAME 'ipHost' DESC 'Abstraction of a host, an IP device' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ ipHostNumber ) MAY ( l $ description $ manager ) ))
5b9a54a1 /opt/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema: line 203 objectclass: AttributeType not found: "manager"
```

Is this a dependency I am missing?

Comment: The slapd loglevel can be configured with the `loglevel` settings, as written in 6.2.1.5 [here](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html). Increase your log verbosity, then I will put a bounty on your question! If you don't increase it, no one will be answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I did run with -1 loglevel and have updated my answer.

Comment: "Some specific object classes and attributes that are not part of the RFC are also needed to operate the NIS service. These objects are defined in the nis.oc.conf and nis.at.conf files " -- do you have those files?

Comment: Other references indicate needing to include cosine.schema

Comment: Including cosine.schema seems to have worked.  I am now doing some testing.  If it works and you can submit this as the answer, I will mare it correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/openshift/openldap/blob/master/2.4.41/contrib/config/schema/nis.schema (among other references) saying:

> Depends upon core.schema and cosine.schema

you'll need to `include` those before including nis.schema:

```
include /opt/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /opt/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
# ...
include /opt/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
```